# Función que en diccionario la clave sea cada letra de la cadena y como valor el numero de veces que aparece en la cadena

Tags: python

Hay algo que está mal por ejemplo en counting1("hello") en vez de dar {'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1} me da {'o': 7}

```
 def counting1(s):
        i = 1
        result = {}
        resultnombres = 0
        if len(s) == 0:
            return {}
        else:
            for c in s:
                    for j in s:
                        if j in c:
                            resultnombres += 1
            result[c] = resultnombres
        return result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, Python viene con ["pilas incluídas"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0206/#batteries-included-philosophy) :-) y en su librería estándar hay de todo. Lo que necesitas te lo hace `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> dict(Counter("hello"))
{'e': 1, 'h': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}
```

Segundo, si quieres implementarlo tú mismo para aprender, tu código tiene un error y es que la línea: `result[c] = resultnombres` sólo la haces tras haber terminado el bucle `for c in s:`, en lugar de *para cada letra del bucle*. Así que sólo almacenas el resultado de la última letra. Además, debes reiniciar el contador `resultnombres` para cada letra, en lugar de una sola vez al principio.

Según esto, debería ser así:

```
def counting1(s):
    i = 1
    result = {}
    if len(s) == 0:
        return {}
    else:
        for c in s:
            resultnombres = 0
            for j in s:
                if j in c:
                    resultnombres += 1
            result[c] = resultnombres
    return result
```

Aunque esto funciona, es bastante ineficiente pues tienes dos bucles anidados, de modo que la complejidad de tu algoritmo es O(n^2), o sea, que crece con el cuadrado del tamaño de la cadena de entrada.

Otra solución más eficiente (además de más breve), que recorre una sola vez la cadena, sería:

```
def counting1(s):
    result = {}
    for c in s:
        if c not in result:
            result[c] = 0
        result[c] += 1
    return result
```

Esta solución aún puede abreviarse más si hacemos uso de otra joyita de la librería estándar: `collections.defaultdict` que permite crear diccionarios en los que, automáticamente, si una clave no existe la añade al intentar acceder a ella, en lugar de generar un error:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def counting1(s):
    result = defaultdict(int)
    for c in s:
        result[c] += 1
    return dict(result)
```

Comment: No conocia **defaultdict**. Se agradece.